# Loop though names depending on f

Tags: r, loops

I have 11 different data frames called brand1, brand2, brand3, ...., brand11. And I need to create a loop that runs through different functions by calling each of these data frames. I have tried different commands that I found in other similar queries such as "assign" but it doesn't work

Comment: Suggested duplicate: [How do I make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207) See my answer there for what you should be doing.

Comment: `lapply()` will probably help you

Comment: If you need more help than that, please make a small reproducible example to show (a) what your data looks like, (b) a specific example of what you're trying to do, and (c) a bit of the code you've tried. Otherwise I don't know what we can add that you haven't seen in "similar queries". [This FAQ gives guidance on making reproducible examples that get good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).